# markdown spell checking with triple nested bullet point

Tags: spell-checking, filetype-markdown

I am confused about what is going on in this example and why spell checking is not working any help is appreciated.

While editing a markdown file with spell checking enabled the following happens:

```
* This line is spellchecked
    - This line is also spellchecked
        - This line is not spellchecked
```

I also noticed that this also doesn't work

```
* This line is really long but spellchecked
    continuation of text after linewrap from the previous line, this line is not spellchecked
```

Indentation is 1 tab character per level.

Google has turned up nothing but since the `-` is not bold on the third bullet as the rest are I assume this is some kind of markdown spec violation but I am not sure which. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Not any help, but just for reference, the same is happening here...

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? It works with 8.0.502

Answer (score 3):

Check the syntax id of the text not spell checked.

First define the command SynID:

```
command SynID  echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

Then move the cursor to the text that is not spell checked and execute `:SynID`. For "normal" text it returns nothing.
I tested your markdown snippet and it returned `markdownCodeBlock` for the third level.

If you just indent by 2 spaces, the third level is spell checked, but the fourth level is detected as `markdownCodeBlock`.

Looks like it was already [reported](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues/125).